# Pylint doesn't handle imports when several projects have same base module name

Tags: python, import, pylint

We've got a series of code projects in different parts of our source tree that all have a base package `company_name`, and some of them import functionality from eachother. This works just fine when running the code, setuptools and declare_namespace handle peicing together the modules. However, pylint doesn't seem to be feeling the mojo, so a large number of files have large high-prio errors `Unable to import X from company_name`. PYTHONPATH doesn't help, maybe some magic in pylints --init-hook=?  Any hints and ideas super welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar problem with import directory-based settings from many projects at once.

My dirty solution is to make symlinks, each with different name (eg. projectA/settings -> projA_settings, projectB/settings -> projB_settings) and then use that import:

```
import projA_settings
```

or

```
import projB_settings
```

Comment: Ok, I tried simlinking in the imported subpackages, but I'm still getting errors from pylint. Obviously this works for you, so it shouldn't be that pylint can't/doesn't handle symlinks. Strangeness.